# Conditional probability with choosing two cards from a deck

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Two cards are picked randomly from a deck. What is the probability that if the first card is Spades, the second card will be a Queen?

**What I have so far:**

Let $A$ be the event the first card is Spades.

Let $B$ be the event the second card is a Queen

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B|A) = \frac{\frac{13}{52}P(B|A)}{\frac{13}{52}}$$

But now i get confused for $P(B|A)$ since its the problem im trying to solve in the first place... I know that $A$ and $B$ are dependent events since  if a spade is drawn it **could** be the Queen spade.

So we we remove that possibility,  which would make the probability of drawing the second queen be $3/51$. But, if that $P(B|A) = 3/51$ wouldnt that be the solution to the question in the first place? What happend to the $13/52$ parts?Also, if the first card is not a queen then shouldn't we consider that case as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the first card is a spade, there are two relevant cases:  either the first card is the queen of spades (probability ${1 \over 13}$), or it is a different spade (probability ${12 \over 13}$).

In the first case, the probability the second card is a queen is ${3 \over 51}$.  In the second case, the probability the second card is a queen is ${4 \over 51}$.  Hence:

$$P({\rm queen}|{\rm spade}) = {1 \over 13}{3 \over 51}+ {12 \over 13}{4 \over 51} = {1 \over 13}$$

Comment: Intuitively your answer makes perfect sense to me. However, in terms of the defined probability equation, i dont understand why it isnt $\frac{\frac{1}{13}\frac{3}{51}}{\frac{1}{13}}\frac{\frac{12}{13}\frac{4}{51}}{\frac{12}{13}}  $

Comment: @shockwave88:  Why it isn't *what*?

Comment: I updated the answer, if u dont mind answering it. I think its that way because of the denominator in the conditional probabilty equation.